# Cannot access Computer drives

Tags: hard-drive

I am new to UBUNTU. I just installed version 14.04

When I click on FILES, under DEVICES, it shows Computer & nothing else. Even in the Computer folder, there are multiple folders but nothing showing a drive (like how in Windows, it used to show as C, D or E)

I connected my external hard disk & that reads just fine but if I copy something, I cannot paste it anywhere.

I have downloaded GParted Partition Editor - and it shows /dev/sda1 (with a little key next to it). Under "file system" it shows as "ext4" and under "mount point" there is a "/". The size is shown as 463 GB which is the size of the Hard disk in built. 
So now of course, I want access to this.

I have read alot of FAQ's on the forum but somehow they all seem to be bouncing over my head & I have not been able to come with a solution. 
PLEASE HELP & PREFERABLY - in an easy step by step way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Linux systems don't use the "drive letter" convention that you are familiar with from Windows devices.  You can easily access the file system on Ubuntu by clicking the folder icon in the Unity launcher.

If there are no additional drives mounted, you will not see anything under Devices except Computer.  Under Computer you should see a list of folders with some familiar names like Documents, Pictures, Videos.  To access these folders just click on them under Computer.  Home will bring you back.

This answer is rather general but so was your question.  If you specify all the steps you took to copy and paste something and describe in what step it failed, people may be able to offer more specific guidance.

Comment: Hey, thanks. As much as you thought my question and your answer was general, it kind of helped me.
I was looking for my drive in the COMPUTER section under DEVICES but it appears that the drive itself is under the HOME section of FILES. Here I see my disk space and am able to copy and paste stuff.

Comment: Thanks! If the answer helped, marking the question as answered or upvoting my response helps my reputation (I'm kinda new here...)